# MAMP PRO testing local WordPress website with xip.io over LAN from iPhone not loading images css correct links etc

Tags: wordpress, mamp-pro

Hiall,

I’m trying to simply test my local MAMP PRO wordpress site on my iPhone through my local LAN network.

I test my on my Mac via the URL which works fine
http://mysite:8888/

For my iPhone
If I go to MAMP PRO select my website/host from the left column and check the via Xip.ic (LAN only) option/checkbox
it provides a URL which is
      http://mysite.10.0.1.6.xip.io:8888

I then send myself an email with this link which I click from the iPhone

When I load http://mysite.10.0.1.6.xip.io:8888 in my iPhone, the URL loads and I can see my website but there is no images, or CSS styling, the sites links are not correct and I only see the sites text.

I understand I need to change the site to load like its loading from mac to my iPhone urls and that I can change the

WordPress Address (URL)
Site Address (URL)

without having to do it in the wp-admin settings screen by adding by doing

```
  define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.10.0.1.6:8888');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://mysite.10.0.1.6:8888');
```

but this does not make a difference either

I’ve also tried

```
 define('WP_HOME', 'http://mysite.10.0.1.6.xip.io:8888');
 define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://mysite.10.0.1.6.xip.io:8888');
```

I’ve found various examples like
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98386/testing-local-server-with-mamp-wordpress-on-mobile-device
http://www.designshifts.com/view-local-wordpress-website-on-your-iphone-or-ipad-with-mamp/

which I have spent hours trying to replicate but I just can’t figure it out!

I’m not sure if it’s because I’m typing my urls / ports different/incorrectly and typing my URL’s incorrectly to include ports etc, or because I have the latest version of MAMP PRO and Yosemite and these examples are a few years old etc, or maybe I need to be clearing the the word press / MAMP cache, restarting on every atempt etc?.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have replaced the home and siteurl in the General Settings. Note: Wp-config alternative hack as you mentioned didn't work for me.

In Mamp Pro, select your host e.g. (example.dev).

1. Check "via Xip.io (LAN only)
2. Under Alias Name, Add your system's static IP (e.g. 192.168.15.4). Default settings will work
3. Save and Restart servers.

Your Images and CSS should appear. BUT links are still not working. I hope you'd help me improving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wordpress settings, change the below:

```
 define('WP_HOME', 'http://mysite.10.0.1.6.xip.io:8888');
 define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://mysite.10.0.1.6.xip.io:8888');
```

To your device local network I.P. address, for example:

```
 define('WP_HOME', 'http://192.168.0.71');
 define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://192.168.0.71');
```

This will work!

Comment: Hi @Siegfried Grimbeek when I do what you suggest
     define('WP_HOME', 'http://10.0.1.6');
     define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://10.0.1.6');
and I go to the URL 
     http://mysite.10.0.1.6.xip.io:8888

I get the same as the original (site loads without any images or CSS styling and links are incorrect if I click a link in the main nav I get a Safari error  message "Cannot open the page because it it could not connect to the server".

Comment: If I add the port 

define('WP_HOME', 'http://10.0.1.6:8888');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://10.0.1.6:8888');

I get the same again site loads no images or styling and get a different error message this time from the server, "Not Found, The requested URL /page/ was not found on this server".

This is the first time I have worked with ip address 10.0.1.6 etc usually for a local it is 192.168.01.1 etc like you suggest maybe that has something to do with it? I'm getting my IP from clicking the "Open network preferences" option and 10.0.1.6 is listed under status on my mac

Comment: Siegfried as shown in the original post the address that I use to view my working site on is 

     http://mysite:8888/ and 
     http://mysite:8888/wp-admin/ 

for admin of the site etc

I am still stuck on this issue, any help would be great.

Comment: Cool, lets see if we can sort this. Here is how my sites look locally: http://localhost:8888/mysite/. Its strange that yours is http://mysite:8888. Where is your localhost directory?

Comment: thanks Siegfried I am using MAMP Pro so I have setup all of my website sites in individual hosts / server names. I have a http://localhost:8888 but I have nothing set to it, when I go to http://localhost:8888 I get MAMP PRO image top left and the message 
The virtual host was set up successfully.

If you can see this page, your new virtual host was set up successfully. Now, web contents can be added and this placeholder page1 should be replaced or deleted.

Server name: localhost
Document-Root: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

1 Files: index.php and MAMP-PRO-Logo.gif

Comment: I'm new to MAMP as of about 2 months ago, all my previous work used to be done on PC with WAMP where I was using localhost in the url for testing etc, but the site I am working on here is fresh built from scratch on MAMP

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to get this working if anyone out there knows or can help please let me know!

Comment: Hi guys, is anyone out there running a MAMP PRO server, and is testing one of there MAMP hosts via mobile or tablet and it is working? If so please let me know I never got this working, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the simplest way I have found is to just go into your database and look for `siteurl` and `home` which are normally record 1 & 2 in the database, and update it to your network IP address.

It can then be visited in the browser from that IP address for anyone on the network.

Wordpress just isn't built to make xip.io work because it defines the site name statically.

[image]